Wordpress shop menu layout view
My website menu is running W ordpress Oxygen currently and my shop menu is in a graphical icon format https://247munchies.co.uk/product-category/product-base/ Apologies I don't know to access the code I'm actually talking about or I would paste it here.
I wondered if there was a way to convert my products to a list view rather than the graphical view (Sort of like Uber and Deliveroo website menus), I have button to switch the page views already. I did not design the website and unfortunately don't have contact with creator anymore as he has moved, I have tried to fiddle around in Oxygen (what it was built on) but my attempts to recreate it to a list view are coming up weak.
I copied one of the pages, added in a single line of product but couldn't align them vertically or create the add to basket button to make it a functioning menu.
Please any assistance is apricated
Thanks in advance
I tried editing a current page and create a section to add products in but couldn't figure out much past adding the div section and image
